# Install gcc on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: python, mac, gcc, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to install the Python Imaging Library on a MacBook running 10.6 Snow Leopard.  I haven't yet found a precompiled binary for OS X, so I need to compile it from source, which means I need gcc.

Thing is, though, it's not my computer (it belongs to the school at which I teach), and Xcode is no longer free.  If I go the route of getting gcc through installing Xcode, then either I have to join the Apple Developer Program or purchase Xcode through the Mac App Store (using my own account, no less).  Neither option is particularly attractive.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there a precompiled PIL binary for 10.6 out there?
2. Is there another way to go about getting gcc for free?

Answer (score 2):

[XCode 3.0](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792) is free through the developer tools web site if you get a free developer account. You can use that to bootstrap [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php), which will compile and install newer versions of gcc, and which will also install PIL.

Comment: Last time I tried (I have a free developer account) I needed to be on a yearly developer program! In the end I got XCode3, but macports is probably a better idea if you don't need the rest of xcode.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking 3 was that version. It still has XCode 3 available for download if you're in the free program, and that's all you need to bootstrap MacPorts, which will install the latest GCC and PIL.

Answer (score 1):

XCode3 is still free and XCode4 is what, $5?

**edit** I'm honestly not sure what this entails, but could be worth checking out: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers

Comment: I don't mind spending the $5. But I don't want to use my personal Mac App Store account on a school machine.  And besides, while Apple is welcome to charge whatever they want for Xcode, gcc should still be free, both as in beer and speech, no?

Comment: Ask your school...

Comment: @Alex: Apple is free to charge for GCC, although I doubt they can legally stop you from redistributing all of Xcode to whoever you want, considering it contains GPL software.

Comment: @Alex Basson neither beer nor speech will ever truly be free. I can see your point (re: school computer). My advice would be to grab XCode 3 (and yes, I was a bit shocked they charge for XCode 4.. kinda pissed me off too)

Answer (score 1):

Buy XCode 4 for lousy 5 USD - what's the point?

Comment: It's not about the money.  It's about using my personal App Store account to purchase software on a machine I don't own, which I'm reluctant to do.

Comment: Downvoted for whatever reason? Better downvote the OP or spend 5 USD for buying a compiler. Kindergarten...

Comment: @RestRisiko yea, I'm not sure but I'm +1 for being in the same boat and making the same argument :P